# i already installed docker 23.0.1 (version) but I want to install Docker 20.10.22 (version) in ubuntu 22.04 Guide me accordingly

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

i already installed docker 23.0.1 (version) but I want to install Docker 20.10.22 (version) in ubuntu 22.04 Guide me accordingly. can't install docker 20.10.22 in ubuntu 22.04

i want to install docker 20.10.22 in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do ?

My first idea would be to use an ubuntu 22.04 image and to install docker in your container, you could access your container with your terminal and do whatever you want inside without side effect on your own system.